# Как скачать apk, сделанный на NativeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-development, nativescript

Потестировал платформу NativeScript для создания мобильных приложений на `JS`/`HTML`.

Как получить apk файл, чтобы дать его людям?

Answer (score 2):

В англоязычной ветке есть аналогичный вопрос. Ответ оттуда

Для сбокри apk для android используйте следующую команду:

`tns build android --release --key-store-path <path-to-your-keystore> --key-store-password <your-key-store-password> --key-store-alias <your-alias-name> --key-store-alias-password <your-alias-password>`

Дополнительная информация: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps

Если вы хотите получить отладочный apk используя `tns debug android --bundle`, то можете найти его здесь

`<your project folder>/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331854/nativescript-vue-how-to-get-the-apk-file)